# What happens with a binary search on an uneven array/table

Tags: binary-search

Let's say we have a table or an array of N-length.
What happens if the length of the table is uneven ?
With an even table the length would be determined by doing N/2.
I would assume that for an uneven table this still holds true.

Does it do N/2 and then take the integer part of the result and use that as "the middle" or does it round up/down ? Or does it do something else entirely ?

Comment: The case you describe is the common one.  The array length needs to be not only even, but a power of two in order for every interval it examines to have even length.  In many languages, `N/2` will automatically truncate to an integer if `N` has integer type.  If you need to write a binary search in a language that does not do that then you will need to convert half-integral indices to integers one way or another.  As long as you are consistent, you can make it work.

Comment: Integers are used, and the division is an integer division, with implied truncation of the remainder. BTW I like to follow E. Dijkstra's convention of using `[0, N>` as the search interval, the right value excluded from the range.